# Preencher valores vazios no python

Tags: python, script

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um script que eu queria preencher alguns valores vazios ao executar o script em python, alguém consegue me ajudar? isso na linha de comando no terminal ao executar o script.[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qTW.png)

Answer (score -3):

Podes passar argumentos ao script para preencher os valores e executas no terminal do seguinte modo `python script.py "key" "value"`.

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) == 3):
    filter_key = sys.argv[1]
    filter_value = sys.argv[2]

    # inserir código aqui
else:
    print("Argumentos inválidos")
```